# Could not find kotlin-compiler-30.1.2.jar

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration2'.
> Could not find kotlin-compiler-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.1.2/kotlin-compiler-30.1.2.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           17.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.